# How to make Visual Studio Code recognise .kv (Kivy) file type?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Kivy (.kv) files use a similar syntax to Python (.py) files. I would like to use the Ctrl-K / Ctrl-C key sequence to comment out lines of code when editing .kv files, as works in Python files. How could I enable that key sequence for .kv files?

Answer (score 1):

This is not officially possible, AFAIK. You could check to see if there's already a [UserVoice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code) to upvote, and if not create one.

It does look like VSCode is prepared to offer such features in the future. If you browse to:

```
C:\Users\YouUserName\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.3.0\resources\app\plugins\vs.language.python
```

And open the file `ticino.plugin.json`, then find:

```
"extensions": [ ".py" ],
```

and change it to:

```
"extensions": [ ".py", ".kv" ],
```

After doing this, and restarting VSCode, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command also works in `.kv` files.

Note that (a) this is a hack, of which I don't know the side effects, and (b) that you will likely loose this setup after VSCode is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest to install the "KvLang" directly from VSCode Marketplace.
Maybe it will be another easy way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you will create an text file, it will give you a option '*Select a language*';

You can just click on it And - Boom! it will give all languages You can use.

If you want to know more just click ===> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview

Thanks